# How do I make KernelDensity normalize to 1?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I'm using the `KernelDensity` module from `sklearn.neighbors`, but the y-axis values are weird. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I would like the y-axis to correspond to the percent probability.

[image]

```
X = data[:, np.newaxis]   
X_plot = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.15).fit(X)
log_dens = kde.score_samples(X_plot)
axis.plot(X_plot[:, 0], np.exp(log_dens), '-',
            label="kernel = '{0}'".format('pft'))
```

Comment: `I would like the y axis to correspond to the percent probability` - what is percent probability?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you looked at `MinMaxScaler` ? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Comment: What do you want to do with the probability? Classification? Outlier detection? Note that with kernel density estimation you are estimating a probability density function of a continuous random variable. There is no way to get a probability for an individual float value, you can only get a probability for the value being in a certain interval, by integrating the density function in that interval.

Answer (score 3):

The y axis in your plots above is already normalized, and corresponds to *probability density* (i.e. the integral under the curve is unity). This is really the only normalization that makes sense for a continuous variable, as the "percent probability" of any particular value in a continuous distribution is exactly zero.